Cannot access LVM2 partition from fedora 40 SSD
I recently upgraded my fedora install from 38 --> 40 and it seemed fine afterwards.  I then tried to copy that installation to a new larger SSD via "dd" and that's when the problems started.  After the dd, I could boot the OS on the new SSD, but it had various errors with several apps, so I mucked around and ultimately ended up doing something bad to both disks, such that they both seemed to be effectively the same and neither would boot.  I was working off a fedora live USB when I tried to fix the problem, and by following gpt a little too blindly, I think I deleted the volume group that the root dir was in, and I think I may have done it to both drives.  After mucking around some more, I decided to bite the bullet and go with a new fresh fedora 40 install on the new SSD and then just work to copy over the root dir from old drive to recover my various files, configs, apps, etc...  However, now that my new fedora 40 machine is up and working fine, I can't seem to access the root from the previous installation SSD.  The previous fedora installation was on a 250GB with 3 partitions (and the new one is a 1TB with 3 partitions).  On the old SSD, the first 2 partitions seem fine and I can mount them fine, but the third is inaccessible.  The third (sdg3) is an LVM2 partition, but I can't seem to mount it or access the files on it.  Various volume related commands like vgscan, pvs, lvs don't return anything, adn I tried using testdisk/phtorec, but phtorec couldn't find any files on sdg3.  ere is what lsblk and photorec show:
sdg      8:96   0 232.9G  0 disk
├─sdg1   8:97   0   200M  0 part
├─sdg2   8:98   0     1G  0 part /run/media/root/d2192ee7-b733-4757-a058-f7a674b093cc
└─sdg3   8:99   0 231.7G  0 part


PhotoRec 7.2, Data Recovery Utility, February 2024
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sdg3 - 248 GB / 231 GiB (RO) - ASMT 2115
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
   P Linux LVM2               0   0  1 30245  32 59  485888000


root@fedora:~# pvscan -ay
  Command does not accept option: --activate y.
root@fedora:~# blkid

/dev/sdg3: UUID="fgJqDG-Sfow-3fzo-HWWl-i068-bSry-UUCfcL" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="69ba55b8-e5b8-4490-8b01-b838bb1109b1"
/dev/sdg1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="CB4D-1B24" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="6198adc0-27fb-4a79-9c77-7defdf79c8be"
/dev/sdg2: UUID="d2192ee7-b733-4757-a058-f7a674b093cc" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1e205e60-1136-4007-aeb4-716e38e42818"

root@fedora:~# pvscan /dev/sdg3
  Command does not accept argument: /dev/sdg3.
root@fedora:~# pvscan
  No matching physical volumes found
root@fedora:~# pvs
root@fedora:~# lvs
root@fedora:~# 

I don't think I've deleted any data from sdg3, and I created a backup .img with ddrescue, but I can't figure out how to recover that partition (and gpt just keeps taking me in circles).  How can I recover the root filesystem from sd3?

Have you tried doing "pvscan -ay" ?   Also, what does "blkid" output?

@davidgo - I added those outputs to the question.

What does  "pvscan /dev/sdg3" and what does "pvscan" output? If one of them does not error, what does "PVS" say afterwards?

@davidgo I updated the description with those commands, but like the other LVM related commands, they don't output anything

It looks like you are deal in "this can break things worse territory" - so you should definitely do bitcopy backups first - https://www.golinuxcloud.com/recover-lvm2-partition-restore-vg-pv-metadata/ may be useful.

ok, thanks for the help.  I'll post back here when I have the time to really dig into that doc for recovery.
On a slightly different note, any idea why testdisk and photorec don't work?

If photorec does not work that is a very bad sign.  It could indicate hardware failure, or you are accessing the wrong device.  photorec reads the raw disk and tries to pick up fragments of data based on the signatures in the file.
